# What do you think about 'Picture of the day' concept?

Tags: discussion

Maybe it would be interesting to have 'Picture of the day'. The theme shoud be free for this.
'Picture of the week' could remain the same, or it could be the best picture from that week from 'picture of the day' themes.

Comment: How would you anticipate it working, whilst working alongside the Picture of the Week, which gets displayed in the header? Where would you expect a picture of the day to show?

Comment: It should work independet of Picture of the week and. Every day a new threat could be created (I could do it) and it would be close 24 hours after. It is not need to show anywhere else, or it could be show near the 'Picture of the week', as a 'picture of the day'. And I suggest it could be in the main site, not in meta and it would not be landscape limited. Week contest could stay in meta.

Comment: It wouldn't be in the form of a question, so wouldn't really fit on the main site without detracting from the main ethos of being a place to find answers to photography related questions. As such, I could see the wider community voting to close them from the main site.

Comment: Ok, I see the point. But than maybe 'Picture of the week' concept in meta is not needed too. It is more like a contest and we have hall of fame too...it is very nice and interesting, but is it also detracting from the main point of q/a ?

Comment: The mods can barely keep up with once a week as it is ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Let's not do that.**

The reason for "Picture of the week" contest is *only* to find a suitable photo for the main page header. It is not a primary feature, and certainly not absolutely necessary, but it's a nice way of keeping the look fresh using some best on-topic works of community. The idea was never to be a contest site, so we shouldn't have more of them. And that's also why the contest should stay in meta - it's not the kind of content users should come to Photography SE for.

Based on experiences with weekly contest, I'd say 24 hours is simply a **too short timeframe**. Sometimes, the weekly contest will get its first entry on second or third day. So, "Picture of the day" would be "the *only* picture of the day". And certainly, there wouldn't be enough time to vote for the entries. Even if you visit the site daily, the pictures that get uploaded after your visit you won't have chance voting for. Upload too late, and only few will see it competing. No competitors, no votes - that's a shabby contest.